# Open new Fragment screen by clicking the button in Activity android

Tags: android-activity, onclick

I have created one activity class in android.i need to clicking button show new fragment class screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FragmentManager class:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.your_fragment_container, yourFragment)
.addToBackStack();
ft.commit();
```